# How to build and install a cloned GitHub library?

Tags: drivers, git

I've used `git clone` to make a local copy of a GitHub repository containing a [video driver](https://github.com/mmind/xf86-video-armsoc) I'd like to use. The local copy contains all of the source for the program; but as a newbie to Ubuntu, I've no idea of what tools or steps are involved in compiling and installing the driver.

I'd really appreciate if anyone could provide a step-by-step guide?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**I still think a newcomer to this shouldn't go to compile drivers themselves, so understand that this is a process where lots can go wrong and you do this at your own risk.**

To begin with, you want to install the proper tools for that. To do so, open a terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential autogen automake make xutils-dev autoconf libtool autoconf-2.64 automake xorg-server-devel xorg-server-utils xorg-util-macros 
git clone https://github.com/mmind/xf86-video-armsoc.git
cd xf86-video-armsoc/
```

Now you should be set to compile your driver. First run the command `sh autogen.sh` - this will create the neccesary files and configure them.

Then you run

```
./configure --with-drmmode=pl111
```

or

```
./configure --with-drmmode=exynos
```

depending on which driver you want to build.

If the configuration process stops in an error, check the last lines which dependencies are missing and install them. Easiest way to find those is running

```
apt-cache search <name>
```

In most cases you will get a fairly long list and have to go through it to find the proper package names to install. This is done then with

```
sudo apt-get install <packagename>
```

Re-run the configure as often as you need until it ends with no errors.

Now that you have configured your build you can use the command `make` to compile your driver followed by `sudo make install` to install it.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you @Videonauth, but `./configure` can't be found  when I try to execute it within the directory, after running `autogen.sh`. There is a file `configure.ac`, but this can't be executed using `./`. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install autoconf`. added this as well to the answer.

Comment: Thanks again, but no dice! `autogen.sh: 27 autogen.sh : ./configure not found` `configure failed`. I'll try looking at line 27 in `autogen.sh` using nano.

Comment: Try  `sudo chmod 777 configure` then `./configure --...`

Comment: This fails, I think the problem may be that `configure` just doesn't exist at all (`no such file or directory`), unless it's definitely `configure.ac` that we're interested in?

Comment: And if you install libtool with `sudo apt-get install libtool`, then run autogen.sh with `bash autogen.sh` and then run ./configure?

Comment: Thanks, the problem was I missing some driver dependencies of ./configure. I needed `autoconf`, `autoconf-2.64`, `automake`, `xorg-server-devel`, `xorg-derver-utils` and `xorg-util-macros`. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for letting me know, i added it into my answer so others who might read it have it directly.

Comment: It's 2022 - I'm running Ubuntu 22.04/Gnome 42 with X11.  If someone could update the chosen answer, please.